# Draw a plot and show points on Python

Tags: python, plot, point

I am using Python to draw a 2-axis plot.

X-axis is 'Q'(integer); Y-axis is 'Z(Q)', a function of 'Q'.

I would like Q to be integer from 0, 1, 2, ..., 10 for example. And I have Z(Q) already defined and it runs okay.

I want to see the plot of Z(Q) versus Q with each point (0, 1, 2, ..., 10) on the plot.

Can I write:

```
for Q in range(0, 10):
   pl.plot(Q,Z(Q))
```

And it returns error.

Error Message:

> name 'Q' is not defined.

How could I change the code in defining Q?

Thank you!

Appendix - Entire Code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

mu = 4.68
cs = 100
co = 300
G = poisson(mu)
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

def Z(Q):
    ES = sum(i*p[i] for i in range(len(p)))
    return co*max((Q-ES), 0) + cs*max((ES-Q), 0)

Qstar = np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))
print(Qstar)


from scipy.integrate import quad
import pylab as pl


for Q in range(0, Qstar):
    pl.plot(Q,Z(Q))
```

And this is my full code, the last two lines do not return any result, the rest is fine. Thank you!

Comment: Please, write which error do you got.

Comment: @Enclis. Thanks! I just updated with error infor

Comment: I have tried the code like this and I have not had a problem, I think the error is elsewhere, you could show the complete code.

Comment: There is one error in the range(0, 2*Qstar) where the Qstar is a float and the value expects an integer. You can cast it to an int. Except that I didn't find any error. Maybe you can check your indentation.

Comment: @Will_Panda Thank you! Just as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the numpy data conversion, this can not be used in the range () function, I have corrected the code considering the above.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

mu = 4.68
cs = 100
co = 300
G = poisson(mu)
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

def Z(Q):
    ES = sum(i*p[i] for i in range(len(p)))
    return co*max((Q-ES), 0) + cs*max((ES-Q), 0)

Qstar = np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))
print(Qstar)

Qstar = int(np.float64(Qstar).item())


from scipy.integrate import quad
import pylab as pl


for Q in range(0, Qstar):
    pl.plot(Q,Z(Q), '*')

pl.show()
```

[image]

Lines:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import poisson, norm

mu = 4.68
cs = 100
co = 300
G = poisson(mu)
p = G.pmf(np.arange(3*mu))

def Z(Q):
    ES = sum(i*p[i] for i in range(len(p)))
    return co*max((Q-ES), 0) + cs*max((ES-Q), 0)

Qstar = np.ceil(poisson.ppf(co/(cs+co), mu))
print(Qstar)

Qstar = int(np.float64(Qstar).item())


from scipy.integrate import quad
import pylab as pl

x = []

y = []

for Q in range(0, Qstar):
    x.append(Q)
    y.append(Z(Q))

pl.plot(x, y)

pl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @eyllance  Thanks! I used your updated code, and transfer the Qstar to 'int' type. It works fine! Additional question, how could I connect the dots into a line?

Comment: Already add the code to join the lines, if my answer helps you mark it as correct please.